# Simple WSDL error "The part '' has an invalid value '' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema"

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I am trying to write a simple wsdl file that has a inline xsd. But I'm getting the below errors marked with '*' in wsdl file. I refered other Stack Overflow question, but none helped on this issue.I've just edited my xsd and wsdl file to include the namespaces in each for more details on the files. You may please note that this are files are I've created in my local machine.Below is my code.

```
        xsd file:


         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/bookService" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/bookService" elementFormDefault="qualified">
     <element name="BookServiceRequest"
     type="tns:BookServiceRequestType">
     </element>

     <complexType name="BookServiceRequestType">
     <sequence>
     <element name="limit" type="int"></element>
     </sequence>
     </complexType>

     <complexType name="BookServiceResponseType">
     <sequence>
     <element name="book" type="tns:BookType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>
     </sequence>
     </complexType>

     <element name="BookServiceResponse"
     type="tns:BookServiceResponseType">
     </element>

     <complexType name="BookType">
     <sequence>
     <element name="title" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
     <element name="author" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
     <element name="published" type="date" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
     </sequence>
     </complexType>
    </schema>

          wsdl file:        
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions name="bookService"
     targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/bookService/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/bookService/"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://www.example.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
     <wsdl:types>
     <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/bookService/">
     <xsd:import schemaLocation="../schema/bookService.xsd"
     namespace="http://www.example.org/bookService/" />
     </xsd:schema>
     </wsdl:types>
     <wsdl:message name="BookServiceRequest">
     **<wsdl:part name="BookServiceRequest" element="tns:BookServiceRequest" />
     </wsdl:message>**
     <wsdl:message name="BookServiceResponse">
     **<wsdl:part name="BookServiceResponse" element="tns:BookServiceResponse" />**
     </wsdl:message>
     <wsdl:portType name="BookServicePortType">
     <wsdl:operation name="fetchBooks">
     <wsdl:input name="BookServiceRequest" message="tns:BookServiceRequest" />
     <wsdl:output name="BookServiceResponse" message="tns:BookServiceResponse" />
     </wsdl:operation>
     </wsdl:portType>
     <wsdl:binding name="BookServiceBinding" type="tns:BookServicePortType">
     <soap:binding style="document"
     transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
     <wsdl:operation name="fetchBooks">
     <soap:operation style="document"
     soapAction="http://www.example.org/bookService/fetchBooks" />
     <wsdl:input name="BookServiceRequest">
     <soap:body use="literal" />
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output name="BookServiceResponse">
     <soap:body use="literal" />
     </wsdl:output>
     </wsdl:operation>
     </wsdl:binding>
     <wsdl:service name="BookService">
     <wsdl:port name="BookServicePort" binding="tns:BookServiceBinding">
     <soap:address location="/service/bookService" />
     </wsdl:port>
     </wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Can you post the full WSDL and XSD (`..\schema\bookService.xsd`?) with namespace declarations and all? What program is giving you this error?

Comment: @sshaw I've editted the file with complete namespaces inside.